# how to download file from server getting error file not found?

Tags: android

can you please tell me how to download file from server ? I am getting error fill not found error ?

```
07-30 17:10:28.849: W/System.err(14900): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /testnaveen: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
07-30 17:10:28.849: W/System.err(14900):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
07-30 17:10:28.849: W/System.err(14900):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
07-30 17:10:28.849: W/System.err(14900):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:128)
07-30 17:10:28.849: W/System.err(14900):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:117)
07-30 17:10:28.849: W/System.err(14900):    at com.mobilecem.atms.GlobalFunction.downloadFileFromServer(GlobalFunction.java:147)
```

I am doing like this

```
public static void downloadFileFromServer(String filename, String urlString) throws MalformedURLException, IOException
    {
        BufferedInputStream in = null;
        FileOutputStream fout = null;
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);

            in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            fout = new FileOutputStream(filename);

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            int count;
            while ((count = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1)
            {
                fout.write(data, 0, count);
                System.out.println(count);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (in != null)
                    in.close();
            if (fout != null)
                    fout.close();
        }
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
```

I call both ways but hot same error why ?

```
GlobalFunction.downloadFileFromServer("test", "http://www.example.com/inputParameters.js");
GlobalFunction.downloadFileFromServer( new File(Activity.this.getFilesDir(),"www").getAbsolutePath(), "url");
```

Comment: Make sure your file is not read-only.  Have provided WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in your manifest?

Comment: Already written in menifest file ..please download file from server

Comment: Make sure your file name is correct and also its uploaded on server.

Comment: it is uploaded on server if you hit the like as given there is file .But what is file name ? i mention anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use Download Manager.**
Advantage of Download Manager:

1. It Automatically retry the download if connection lost.
2. It Takes Care of Worker Thread i.e Background Thread .
3. It Shows your downloaded status with progress status in Navigation Tray

   ```
   package com.example.testing;
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.app.DownloadManager;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.net.Uri;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.os.Environment;
   import android.util.Log;

   public class FileDownloading extends Activity
   {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       startDownload("http://www.example.com/inputParameters.js","inputParameters.js");
   }
   public void startDownload(String url ,String fileName)
   {
       Log.d("Download Url", url);
       DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
       request.setTitle("Your File Name");
       request.setDescription(fileName+" is downloading..");
       request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName);
       DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE); 
       long downloadID = downloadManager.enqueue(request); 
   }
    }
   ```

Don't forget to use Internet and Storage permission in `manifest.xml`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to invoke network related operation if you are using HONEYCOMB or higher.

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19162272/httpclient-executehttppost-on-android-4-2-error)

Comment: You have to rewrite it to use AsyncTask